# Can I use my swap memory to increase storage for Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ram, swap

I have accidentally (well actually carelessly) provided 11gb swap memory for my dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 installation with Windows 10. I have allocated 25gb to the root partition, which I would like to expand. Can I convert my swap memory to root storage in Ubuntu? If so, how? If not, any alternatives?

I'm a complete Linux noob, so sorry if this is a dumb question!

Edit: It is a swap partition that I'm talking about

Edit 2:
The following is what I see in Gparted. `/ext4` is my root partition, and the one below `unallocated` is the `linux-swap`. Can I do the resizing then?

[image]

Comment: You haven't said if it was a swap file, or swap partition.  Swap files can be changed easily too (even easier than swap partitions).

Comment: it was a swap partition

Comment: @guiverc can I resize swap partitions with gparted as well?

Comment: Yep, though I tend to just delete them, do what I need, then use the space over to re-create swap (or you could drop expand '/' to use all space, and use swapfile instead as it's easily changed). It's done from the *live* system (eg. installation media).  If you delete/re-create, you'll need to amend the UUID in your *file system table* (`/etc/fstab`) and expanding "/" may require you to re-write your MBR (ie. `grub-install`) but I fix that if needed (again using *live* media)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use disk management tool gparted. If not installed you can install it using `$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install gparted`. Launch the app as a super user `$ sudo gparted` and enter the password when prompted. You will see the logical representation of your storage device.

It is possible to make these changes if and only if your swap partition is adjacent to the right of the root partition otherwise you are limited! If this is true, proceed to swapoff and resize your partition from left to right creating an unallocated space adjacent to the right of the root partition. After that move the root partition to the right adding the an unallocated space. A green icon should appear to the top asking to apply all changes. Click and proceed as prompted and you are good to go.

For detailed information on how to use gparted find it [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Hope this serves your purpose. Success!

Comment: Do I need to do this using a usb live boot? Or can I do this normally?

Comment: You only need a USB live boot when you don't need to install gparted. Otherwise, you need to note that for you to interact with a partition you should unmount it first and for the swap you swapoff. To be specific, if you try it normally as you stated it, you will get unmount partition error as root is critical the system. So go for the USB live boot.

Comment: I have edited my question. could you check the image and see if resizing is possible or not?

Comment: Answer edited. Follow to get help.

Comment: The comment about not needing to use live USB to boot is wrong. You will need to unmount your root partition to resize it. Unmounting your root partition while Ubuntu is running from it is like trying to change a tire of your car while driving it. In gparted you will see a ️ icon next to the root partition.